# Referring to registered result from prior run ansible play

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Looking to retrieve value of `register`ed output in subsequent playbook, but is yielding in undesired result.

How do I capture just word 'SUCCESSFUL" from first play to second one in below playbook?

(**edit** - added debug also) Playbook content :

```
 cat play1.yml
---
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
   - name: Parse result info
     shell: |
       cmd: |
       echo "Result output goes here. Some Exception number details : Exception from HRESULT" | grep "Exception from HRESULT"
       excep_status=`echo $?`
       if (( $excep_status == 0)) ; then
         echo "SUCCESSFUL"  # Exception present
       elif (( $excep_status == 1)) ; then
         echo "FAILED"
       fi
     register: ExcepStatus
     delegate_to: localhost

   - debug: msg="{{ExcepStatus.stdout}}"

   - name: echo ExcepStatus
     shell: |
       echo {{ ExcepStatus.stdout }}
     delegate_to: localhost
```

Here is simple inventory file

```
$ cat inv
localhost
```

Here is run result:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inv play1.yml
    PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Parse result info] ************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> localhost]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************

    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "Result output goes here. Some Exception number details : Exception from HRESULT\nSUCCESSFUL"
    }

TASK [echo ExcepStatus] *************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo Result output goes here. Some Exception number details : Exception from HRESULT\nSUCCESSFUL\n", "delta": "0:00:00.011982", "end": "2023-12-18 05:00:49.203555", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2023-12-18 05:00:49.191573", "stderr": "/bin/sh: line 1: SUCCESSFUL: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: line 1: SUCCESSFUL: command not found"], "stdout": "Result output goes here. Some Exception number details : Exception from HRESULT", "stdout_lines": ["Result output goes here. Some Exception number details : Exception from HRESULT"]}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Adding `-q` option to `grep` did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

You can [cache](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html#cache-plugins) the variable. For example, configure cache [ansible.builtin.jsonfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/jsonfile_cache.html)

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg

[defaults]
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /var/cache/ansible
fact_caching_prefix = cache_
fact_caching_timeout = 86400

  ...
```

and create the directory on the controller (fit the owner and permissions to your needs)

```bash
shell> sudo mkdir /var/cache/ansible
shell> sudo chown root:adm /var/cache/ansible
shell> sudo chmod g+w /var/cache/ansible
```

When you run the below playbook for the first time

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - block:

        - debug:
            msg: ExcepStatus is undefined
        - command: echo SUCCESSFUL
          register: out
        - set_fact:
            ExcepStatus: "{{ out }}"
            cacheable: true
  
      when: ExcepStatus is undefined

    - debug:
        var: ExcepStatus.stdout
```

you'll create and cache the variable *ExcepStatus*. See the parameter [cacheable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html#parameter-cacheable)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l test_01

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  msg: ExcepStatus is undefined

TASK [command] ******************************************************************************
changed: [test_01]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************
ok: [test_01]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  ExcepStatus.stdout: SUCCESSFUL

  ...
```

Take a look at the cache

```yaml
shell> cat /var/cache/ansible/cache_test_01 
{
    "ExcepStatus": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": [
            "echo",
            "SUCCESSFUL"
        ],
        "delta": "0:00:00.009163",
        "end": "2023-12-18 07:11:26.221247",
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "",
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2023-12-18 07:11:26.212084",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "SUCCESSFUL",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "SUCCESSFUL"
        ]
    }
```

Now, when you run the playbook, the play will read the variable *ExcepStatus* from the cache

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l test_01

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
skipping: [test_01]

TASK [command] ******************************************************************************
skipping: [test_01]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************
skipping: [test_01]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  ExcepStatus.stdout: SUCCESSFUL

  ...
```

Fit the [timeout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/jsonfile_cache.html#parameter-_timeout) to your needs.